# Python subprocess check_output and call yielding different results for the same arguments to pwgen

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using the subprocess `call()` method to execute the `pwgen` utility to create a 12 character password. When I use `check_output()` I get a different result for the same arguments.

Here's a working code snippet:

```
import tempfile
import subprocess
import os

f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
f.write('random data\n')
f.close()
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/pwgen', "-H", f.name, "12", "1"])
print subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/pwgen', "-H", f.name, "12", "1"])
os.unlink(f.name)
```

Sample output is:

> rioH7IeSu6th
>   giyahvoopehi

I would expect the result to be the same in both cases.  Does anyone know what I need to do to get the output of `check_output()` and `call()` to match?

Comment: Interestingly using `subprocess.Popen` returns the same as `check_output`.  However, both are wrong as running the same command from the shell returns the same value as `subprocess.call`.  :/